# Is casting implicit in C when computing a sum into a larger value?

Tags: c, casting

I am working on a 16-bit processor, so most of my data is in 16-bit except where necessary.

If I have two 16-bit variables `a` and `b` and sum them together into a 32-bit variable, what will the compiler do?

```
uint16_t x, y;
uint32_t z;
x = 65504;
y = 65503;
z = x + y;
```

Will the result in z be identical to `z = (uint32_t)x + (uint32_t)y`, or do I need to cast the result?

I have tried this on my compiler and the casts don't seem to make any difference, but this might just be a compiler oddity for this little embedded processor.

Comment: And what processor is that, precisely ?

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon And why is this relevant for an answer?

Comment: If you get `z == 131007` it means your compiler is not using 16-bit int

Comment: I've never encountered a compiler for a 16 bit CPU which would use 32 bit int. So it would be quite interesting to know which CPU and compiler that are used.

Comment: @Olaf: a 16-bit CPU may or may not have 32-bit registers, and those 32-bit registers may or may not have arithmetic capabilities. This can make a big difference to answer the question.

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon: No, it does not matter. All we need to know which width `int` has on the system. The internal register width does not matter. Nevertheless, we need a [mcve]. (Not that I'm not interested in which CPU it is. It is just not relevant for the question).

Comment: @lundin I think that you're right, the CPU behavior seems strange, but the right question should be about compiler compliance to standard. If the compiler is not strictly conform to C99-11 standards it's very difficult to answer. On the other hand it could be normal on some platforms using fixed point DSP to have 16bits bus and use 32bits integers.

Comment: @Frankie_C bus width and register width are not related to each other. Pentium 2/3/4 use a 64-bit bus and nowadays double/triple/quaduple channel memory controllers have a much bigger bus. The old 16-bit 8088 also has only a 8-bit bus

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc. Of course bus and and register width are not related, but some fixed point DSP architectures have register width 16 bits wide (as their bus) and accumulator 32 bits wide for overflow-underflow handling. Anyway the point remains that the behavior is dependent from compiler compliance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C99 onwards,<sup>*</sup> operands to arithmetic operands are implicitly promoted to be at least as big as `int`, as part of the *usual arithmetic conversions*.  So the behaviour of your code depends on the native size of `int` on your platform.

If your `int` is 32-bit, then your code is equivalent to:

```
z = (int)x + (int)y;
```

If your `int` is 16-bit, then no conversion will occur, and you would get incorrect results due to integer overflow.

---

<sub>* Prior to C99, the promotion rules were less well-defined (although I forget the details).</sub>

Comment: A cast is something done explicitly by the programmer. The compiler will never "cast" something. It may however implicitly _convert_ types. A cast will trigger a conversion. They are different terms - cast refers to the type cast operator.

Comment: @Lundin - Fair!  Fixed now :)

Comment: Makes sense. This compiler probably is set up to convert arithmetic up to 32-bit to make it more familiar, even if it is not compliant with the spec. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @TomOldbury: 32-bit arithmetic is *required* by the spec if in this case, if `int` in 32 bits.

Comment: @TomOldbury No, a 16 bit compiler will not use 32 bit ints or something is very weird with the compiler implementation.

Comment: The promotion rules didn't change in C99 , other than the addition of `long long`

Answer (score 5):

On a 16 bit processor, the size of `int` will be 16 bits.

Therefore, an operation like `x + y` with both operands of `uint16_t` will not get implicitly promoted, it is already of the same size as an `int`. The operation will be carried out on 16 bits and therefore overflow in this case. The result of the operation will be of type `uint16_t`.

You need to cast one or both operands to `uint32_t` to prevent this.

The type of `z` has nothing to do with the `+` operation whatsoever.

Comment: I didn't read Oliver answer earlier, I understood about the explicit type casting,  that's why deleted my abysmal question.

Comment: If int is 16-bit then there is no overflow as `uint16_t` remains unsigned - arithmetic will be done mod 65535

Comment: @M.M Kind of depends on who's definition of overflow you use. Indeed the C standard term overflow doesn't apply to unsigned types. The English term does apply though.

Comment: On a 16 bit processor, the size of int *may* be 16 bits. There is no guarantee that there is a direct connection between cpu integer width and `int`. `int`s however are always *at least* 16 bits wide in C.

Comment: @Clearer Except in every real-world system encountered this holds true, at least until now. Which makes me think that the op is using some very strange compiler port or possibly that they got something wrong. Using a 32 bit integer type for a 16 bit CPU would result in remarkably inefficient code.

Comment: @Lundin Absolutely true. It is worth nothing however. Plenty of stuff have been made that was "correct C" because it just happened to work on some broken compiler on some very specific cpu for some very specific operating system.